# Tesseract Android Very Slow

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, image-processing, tesseract

I am using Tesseract in my app. However, it is very slow. I was just wondering if anyone could give me some suggestions on how to make it faster? For instance, what is the best size of image?

Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: How much is slow? Processing a FullHD image it takes 10 seconds on my DualCore 1.4Ghz ARMv7a device, but it take only 3 seconds on newer Snapdragon 835 QuadCore 2.3GHz ARMv8. PS: does tesseract compiled as library? does it compiled for bot ARMv7 and ARMv8 platforms?

Comment: If your app is dedicated to android only - you should probably consider using [google vision ocr sdk](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/text-overview) instead of tesseract.

Comment: I used the google vision ocr sdk, and it was faster and more accurate, so thank you so much for your suggestion, I really appreciate it!